# Alternative download

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Do you know where I should post asking where to download something that ***are/used*** to be ***originally/still*** on a ***virus site/taken down***? Those questions are circling my head needing to be answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nowhere on our network.

Requests for resources are pretty universally off-topic on our sites.