# Why only two downvotes shown instead of nine?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, down-votes, reputation-history

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262778/user3583166) user asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234640/alternative-download) yesterday and it received nine down votes. But looking in his [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262778/user3583166?tab=reputation) I see only two. Why? I understand that down votes didn't affect his rep, but if so, why two down votes of those nine **were** shown?

> [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design. A user can never go below 1 reputation, any downvotes when the user is *at* 1 are not generally not recorded if they are the only events in a day.

Take [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3694168/user) for example, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3786562/user3786562). All they received is downvotes, so nothing is recorded in the reputation history.

The user you found made one accept, then got downvoted again.

When there are events in a day that do give reputation, then you get to see the events that don't as well; on the 27th [the question received two downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/234640/timeline).

The order of events is:

- 26th: 7 downvotes were given, no record in history needed as the user was at 1.
- 27th: 2 downvotes, then the accept, putting the user to +3. All appear in the record.
- 28th: 1 downvote, user goes from +3 to 1 again.

Comment: That's not true though, it clearly shows two downvotes in the reputation history. The actual question is *why*?

Comment: "any downvotes when the user is at 1 are not recorded"? Why are empty downvotes shown in my screenshot then?

Comment: THX for explanations!